# Creating session not working

Tags: java, json, jsp, aem

I'm following this code here http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/submitting-mobile-form-data-cq.html . First I tried to create session with the following code from createuser.json.jsp which is running on author instance and its working fine -

```
   <%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
   <%@ page import="org.apache.sling.jcr.api.SlingRepository" %>
   <%@ page import="com.day.cq.security.UserManager" %>
     <%@ page import="com.day.cq.security.UserManagerFactory" %>
  <%@ page import="com.day.cq.security.User" %>
   <%@ page import="com.day.cq.security.Authorizable" %>
  <%@ page import="com.day.cq.security.profile.Profile" %>
   <%@ page import="java.util.Iterator" %>
  <%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
 <%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
 <%@ page import="javax.jcr.Repository" %>
 <%@ page import="javax.jcr.Session" %>
 <%@ page import="javax.jcr.SimpleCredentials" %>
 <%@ page import="org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.JcrUtils" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.sling.commons.json.io.*" %><%

 final SlingRepository repos = sling.getService(SlingRepository.class);
 final UserManagerFactory umFactory = sling.getService(UserManagerFactory.class);
 Session session = null;
 try{
 session = repos.loginAdministrative(null); // I'm able to create session
   catch (Exception e)
   {
 System.out.println("Exception Occured: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  finally
   {
  session.logout(); 
 session = null;
  }%>
```

but above code for creating session does not work on publish instance. So, I modified the code as below and tried to run on author instance but in this case createuser.json.jsp is not called. I do not see Sysout statement that I added -

```
 <%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
 <%@ page import="org.apache.sling.jcr.api.SlingRepository" %>
 <%@ page import="com.day.cq.security.UserManager" %>
<%@ page import="com.day.cq.security.UserManagerFactory" %>
  <%@ page import="com.day.cq.security.User" %>
 <%@ page import="com.day.cq.security.Authorizable" %>
 <%@ page import="com.day.cq.security.profile.Profile" %>
  <%@ page import="java.util.Iterator" %>
 <%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
 <%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
  <%@ page import="javax.jcr.Repository" %>
  <%@ page import="javax.jcr.Session" %>
   <%@ page import="javax.jcr.SimpleCredentials" %>
  <%@ page import="org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.JcrUtils" %>
   <%@ page import="org.apache.sling.commons.json.io.*" %><%
  final SlingRepository repos = sling.getService(SlingRepository.class);
  final UserManagerFactory umFactory = sling.getService(UserManagerFactory.class);
  try
   { System.out.println("Hello session creating");
     Repository repository = JcrUtils.getRepository("http://somehost:4502/crx");
        Session session = repository.login(new SimpleCredentials("admin",  
      "admin".toCharArray()),"crx.default"); 
     System.out.println("session: " + session);
     catch (Exception e)
      {
   System.out.println("Exception Occured: " + e.getMessage());
     }
   finally
    {
    session.logout(); 
   session = null;
    }%>
```

If I remove the following lines then createuser.json.jsp is called.

```
     Repository repository = JcrUtils.getRepository("http://somehost:4502/crx");
        Session session = repository.login(new SimpleCredentials("admin",
      "admin".toCharArray()),"crx.default");
```

Please let me know whats wrong I'm doing here. Appreciate your help.

Comment: first code sample does not seem complete, it should not compile catch without a try

Comment: Is it on purpose that the URL is different?

Comment: @FredericClose, It was a typo. I've updated code.

Comment: @Henry, could you please tell me which URL you are referring to? I've updated somehost.com to somehost. It was a type. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Suddenly it started working. Do not know what was wrong when I was doing it from publish. The users are created in publish instance. Can I replicate users to author instance through reverse replication?

Comment: Yes using a reverse replication workflow, that pulls them from the publish instance.